# How to load google ics file for custom duration date?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I want to sync events from google calendar to save to mysql database. when I check it from google calendar it provide the ics url file and I can load it to my program. But it provide all the events. How can I get events by custom date?

Comment: use https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list instead and set max and min times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is not possible to do.*

#### More Information:

The ICS format is a universal calendar format designed for an easy way of sending event and scheduling data between applications.

While it is possible to create an ICS file containing all the details of a Google Calendar, Google does not provide a way of allowing you to pick events by custom date, at least via the API.

#### Workaround:

You can use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar) - specifically the [`Events: list`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) method to get a list of events, specifying the time frame for which you wish to retrieve events, but from there you will either have to process the response in a different way (the API response comes in a JSON file as demonstrated [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#response)), or you will have to convert this data into the iCalendar format before putting it into your database.

#### References:

- [iCalendar - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar)
- [Events: list | Calendar API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)